# Does listening to changes via Firestore ignore some documents if the current changes are big and prioritize based to instructions on the latest event?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**Step 1 :**

Let's say we have a collection called 'chatLive'in `Firestore` and it contains some `docs` let's say 50K `docs`

**step 2:**

```
void chatLiveListner(){
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('chatLive')
      .where('isDeleted', isEqualTo: false)
      .orderBy('timesTamp', descending: true)
      .limit(10)
      .snapshots()
      .listen((event) {
    // action
  });
}
```

Okay when i call `chatLiveListner()` , i know that i will get the latest 10 updated `docs` based on my limit value `.limit(10)` then I understand that I will receive the latest 10 docs continuously IF ANY

Let's imagine now that in the same (((session))) or (((The listener's connection was never interrupted or reset)))  , thousands of new documents were entered by users at the same moment. Will the listener follow all of them and get them 10 by 10 (Regardless of the snapshots numbers or any.)., or will it "miss" all of them except the last 10 documents?

"You can imagine it as being in a chat room with thousands of continuous messages."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your listener is not guaranteed to receive every single document that gets added to the collection.  The only guarantee that you get with a listener is that the latest snapshot will contain the most recent documents that satisfy the query *at that moment in time*.  If the query results change after that, then the listener will *eventually* receive a new set of results for the query, but not necessarily everything that might have changed since the prior snapshot.

A listener doesn't subscribe to an exact series of changes to query results.  A listener subscribes to the most recent set of documents for a query. Under good network conditions your listener might see all the changes, but it is just not a guarantee, especially if there is a disruption in the network connection (even a very short one), or there are too many changes to observe.