# "Does the continued initialize/cancel Firestore listener negatively affect it's natural behavior ?"

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I asked a question on the following link

[Does listening to changes via Firestore ignore some documents if the current changes are big and prioritize based to instructions on the latest event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78171372/does-listening-to-changes-via-firestore-ignore-some-documents-if-the-current-cha/78171738#78171738)

the answer was by @Doug Stevenson

> Your listener is not guaranteed to receive every single document that
> gets added to the collection. The only guarantee that you get with a
> listener is that the latest snapshot will contain the most recent
> documents that satisfy the query at that moment in time. If the query
> results change after that, then the listener will eventually receive a
> new set of results for the query, but not necessarily everything that
> might have changed since the prior snapshot.
>
> A listener doesn't subscribe to an exact series of changes to query
> results. A listener subscribes to the most recent set of documents for
> a query. Under good network conditions your listener might see all the
> changes, but it is just not a guarantee, especially if there is a
> disruption in the network connection (even a very short one), or there
> are too many changes to observe.

And the answer supported my concerns that were worrying me , So I thought of a way to track the events where the listener doesn't miss any new detail.

```
  void cancelMyListner(){
    if(streamSubscription!=null){
      streamSubscription!.cancel();
      streamSubscription = null ;
    }
  }



  StreamSubscription? streamSubscription ;
  void initMyListner(DocumentSnapshot? startAfterValue){
    cancelMyListner();
    CollectionReference myCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('payments');

    ///  if it was first call
    final finalStream = startAfterValue==null?
         myCollection
        .orderBy('docDate',descending: true)
        .limit(10)
        .snapshots()
        :
        /// otherwise keep track last updated doc using startAfterDocument
         myCollection
        .orderBy('docDate',descending: false)
        .startAfterDocument(startAfterValue)
        .limit(10)
        .snapshots();

    streamSubscription = finalStream.listen((event) {
      if(event.metadata.isFromCache||event.metadata.hasPendingWrites||event.docs.isEmpty)return;
      
      // some action {....}

      // track last seen doc and init lisner again with passing the value (looping)
      initMyListner(event.docs.first);
    });

  }
```

According to the tests conducted so far, it has been great, but I'm worried that continued re-preparation may have a negative impact , NO ?

Comment: Please edit the question to state more clearly what the "negative impact" is that you're worried about.  Any possible side-effect could be considered "negative", but you should spell out your concerns specifically.  You should also explain what your strategy is here.  It's not clear from your question how this code is expected to solve any particular problem.

Comment: I will add that the only way to make sure your app gets every record of change is to store each change as a separate document, then query for all of them.  You will be guaranteed to get all the changes without having to worry about whether or not some listener receives all the updates to a single document.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that a listener sees every document, you should not put a `limit` clause on the query.

If you want to track what changed since a certain moment in time, you'll need to:

1. Ensure each document has an associate moment in time, i.e. by storing a timestamp in its fields.
2. Keep track of the last moment in time that the client has seen, i.e. store a timestamp value locally.
3. [Use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) in your code to only request documents with a timestamp after the last moment in time that the client has seen.

Comment: However, this strategy will fail if two documents have the same timestamp but are not actually created at the same time. If the application gets the first before the second, it will never see the second.  Using a server timestamp might help reduce the risk of error, but does that really guarantee that both of the documents always end up together in any given query?  In other words, does use of a server timestamp guarantee consistency for any query?

Comment: "if two documents have the same timestamp but are not actually created at the same time" That sounds like something you'll want to prevent at document creation, for example by using server-side timestamps. --- If duplicate timestamp are valid in your use-case, you can pass both the timestamp and the document ID of the last document you saw - as shown in the documentation on [using a pagination query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Don't you think that my code in my previous question is a good strategy and near of what you ask me to to do ? keeping track the last doc seen and then use .startAfterDocument(startAfterValue) Continuously in every time there events call ? like looping at the same listener (cancel-Re-initialization) , note that i already storing timestamp for per document

Comment: Your code has a limit clause. If you want to guarantee that all document changes are seen, you should not use a limit clause. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯